# Core dump error while using arrays. Why segmentation fault?

Tags: arrays, c

I can't understand why I'm receiving this error.
I'm new to arrays so I can understand that I might have made a mistake somewhere.

```
make -s
 ./main
Enter number of students: 1

For student 1,
Enter Surname: test
Enter Mark for MOD100: 1
Enter Mark for MOD101: 2
Enter Mark for MOD102: 3
Enter Mark for MOD103: 4
Enter Mark for MOD104: 5
Enter Mark for MOD105: 6
Student Name    MOD100  MOD101  MOD102  MOD103MOD104  MOD105  Overall
signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

```

As far as I can see my code is correct, the second part is a WIP.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int numofstudents = 0;
  int i;
  int j;
  int sum;

  char names[numofstudents][1];
  int modules[numofstudents][6];
  
  printf("Enter number of students: ");
  scanf("%i", &numofstudents);


  for (i = 0; i < numofstudents; ++i) 
  
  {
    
    printf("\nFor student %d,\n", i + 1);
    printf("Enter Surname: ");
    scanf("%s", &names[i]);
    printf("Enter Mark for MOD100: ");
    scanf("%i", &modules[1][i]);
    printf("Enter Mark for MOD101: ");
    scanf("%i", &modules[2][i]);
    printf("Enter Mark for MOD102: ");
    scanf("%i", &modules[3][i]);
    printf("Enter Mark for MOD103: ");
    scanf("%i", &modules[4][i]);
    printf("Enter Mark for MOD104: ");
    scanf("%i", &modules[5][i]);
    printf("Enter Mark for MOD105: ");
    scanf("%i", &modules[6][i]);
  }

  
  printf("Student\t");
  printf("Name\t");
  printf("MOD100\t");
  printf("MOD101\t");
  printf("MOD102\t");
  printf("MOD103\t");
  printf("MOD104\t");
  printf("MOD105\t");
  printf("Overall\n");
  
  for (i = 0; i < numofstudents; ++i)
  {

    printf("%4d\t", i + 1);
    printf("%4s\t", names[i][1]);
    printf("%4i\%\t", modules[1][i]);
    printf("%4i\%\t", modules[2][i]);
    printf("%4i\%\t", modules[3][i]);
    printf("%4i\%\t", modules[4][i]);
    printf("%4i\%\t", modules[5][i]);
    printf("%4i\%\t", modules[6][i]);

  }




  return 0;
}
```

I have tried entering the received values in different ways but this error appears every time.

Comment: `int numofstudents = 0;` So, how much memory do you think is allocated here: `char names[numofstudents][1]; int modules[numofstudents][6];`? Also, please remember that array indices are zero-based in C.

Comment: @Bob__ I'm not entirely sure how memory allocation works. I have seen that core dumps are usually caused by the code trying to access memory it doesn't have permission to access, but I am not sure what this actually means and how to fix it.

Comment: Well, it means that `names` is declared as an array of **0** arrays of **1** char. At the very least you should scan the value of `numofstudents` *before* declaring those and *probably* make some more space to store all the characters in the names (plus the null terminator).

Answer (score 2):

You arrays do not have any elements. When you try to access such array you always access it outside the bounds. It is an Undefined Befaviour.

You need to define arrays when you have scanned the user input.

```
int main() {
  int numofstudents = 0;
  int i;
  int j;
  int sum;

  
  printf("Enter number of students: ");
  if(scanf("%i", &numofstudents) != 1) {/* error handling*/}

  char names[numofstudents][1];
  int modules[numofstudents][6];
```

Also you need to index the array the way round ie : `scanf("%i", &modules[i][1]);`

Another problem is that indexes are from zero not one and you need to start from `scanf("%i", &modules[i][0]);` and finish `scanf("%i", &modules[i][5]);`

Comment: Technically speaking, even defining any array type with one of dimensions equal to zero is UB (i.e. `typedef int T[0][3];`) even though no 0-sized array is created.

Comment: @tstanisl Yes I think it is a GCC extension

Answer (score 0):

0_________ is correct that your indexes are wrong.  I just wanted to point out that you are creating a Variable Length Array (VLA). `int numofstudents = something;` followed by `char names[numofstudents][1];` is creating a VLA because the value of `numofstudents` will not be known at compile time. To avoid this, just make a constant sized array:

```
#define STUDENTS_MAX 100

int numofstudents = 0;
char names[STUDENTS_MAX][1];

scanf("%i", &numofstudents);

// Now, don't allow the user to enter anything over STUDENTS_MAX
if (numofstudents > STUDENTS_MAX) {
    numofstudents = STUDENTS_MAX;
}
```

This will also solve your problem of writing out of bounds.

To avoid accidentally creating a VLA, you can use `-Werror=vla` as build option in gcc or clang.  Not sure if MSVC has an option like this.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid "creating" VLA? What is wrong with VLAs?

Comment: @0___________ Not saying it wouldn't work.  I tend to avoid them because they feel like a black box that is hard to reason about what's going on under the hood.  The main point of the answer was to point it out. It is very easy to create one without realizing it and something every C programmer should know.  Maybe `-Wvla` just so you are aware.  Either way, a fixed buffer solves the same problem.

Comment: It is wrong what you write. VLAs are very useful, especially when used as pointers to VLAs.

Comment: *"Not sure if MSVC has an option like this."* IIRC their "option" is to take the "optional" status of VLAs (since C11, we'll see from C23) to the letter and just don't implement them.

Comment: @Bob__ so another reason not to use them?  I never said they aren't useful.  Personally, I don't like them.  But you *should* be aware of when you are making one.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Bob__'s comment

> make some more space to store all the characters in the names (plus the null terminator)"

... there's another out of bounds error waiting even after making `numofstudents` not 0.

The question code `char names[numofstudents][1]` allocates `names[i]` to have one single `char` per student, not "many chars" that you are expecting — and which you're asking the user to input. When you try to `scanf` a string into each one, I expect that will cause scanf to try to write memory beyond the bounds allocated to `names`

Instead: You need to allocate enough space in `names[numofstudents][?]` for `scanf` to write the name into, including the char taken by the null terminator.

This is where @Jason's answer comes in, it's common to have some kind of constant `NAME_MAX` which you pick to be "long enough" for any name that will be input.

e.g.

```
#define STUDENT_NAME_MAX 100

...

char names[numofstudents][STUDENT_NAME_MAX];
```